# REGEX: How Do I Write a Negative REGEX for a HTML Pattern value?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-5, regex-negation

I currently have a contact form where I reject values in text fields that have email addresses and URLs. I use these REGEX expressions in my Rails controller. I want to replicate this and use it in my HTML pattern field instead.

```
regex_email   = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/   
regex_url     = /^(http|ftp|https)|[.][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]/
regex_message = /seo|captcha|sales|Б|Г|Д|ё|Ж|П|Ф|И|й|Л|Ц|Ш|Щ|Э|Ю|Я/i
regex_all     = /#{regex_email}|#{regex_url}|#{regex_message}/i
```

I have created locale hashes for regex_url, regex_message, and regex_url. I want to negate hose values then add AND operators of some kind and use something like my example below as my pattern.

```
"data-pattern" => "NOT#{regex_email}AND NOT#{regex_url}AND NOT#{regex_message}"
```

Either this or something like this where the negation of my hashes is added to the hash itself.

```
"data-pattern" => "#{regex_email}AND#{regex_url}AND#{regex_message}"
```

I've searched a good number of links about AND and NOT but the discussions are not really clear.

I'm asking this question because I have not been successful in coding regex expressions that only include letters, numbers, period, or hyphen. All the solutions I found still allowed any single character when I included the . in my regex. I even tried escaping it but it still matches.

Comment: If you're setting it in the HTML pattern field for the client it can be disabled. Depending on how important it is for you to prevent those items from being entered, it might be best to keep it server-side.

Comment: That's true. The code I have works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your expressions *regex_email, regex_url and regex_message* are working reliably, and that you're looking for a logical *negation* of your *regex_all* pattern on the *regex level* (that is how I understand your question).
You can make use of a slightly modified *negative lookahead* logic, like so:

```
/^(?!.*#{regex_email})(?!.*#{regex_url})(?!.*#{regex_message})/
```